# A utility library with primitive types tryParse methods in java?

Tags: java, java-8

In Java when parsing a Date or an int or any primitive type from a String, it needs to be done in a try catch because a ParseException could occur. It would be nice if there was a method tryParse that did not throw an exception but rather returns true or false if the String could or could not be parsed. There are few examples online that describe writing an utility function for parsing an int. But I believe this would also be necessary for a few more types: int, long, Date, etc...Because this is such a common problem I was wondering is there a utility library that already has these tryParse methods for primitive types?

Comment: Welcome to Java... if you'd rather a null return than an exception you should probably be writing C.

Comment: sorry I meant it should return true or false, let me edit the question

Comment: The first place to look for this kind of things is the [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) project. They have loads of utility classes.

Comment: a parse should return the date, int, long, whatever and never true/false unless you are parsing a boolean. what you want is php style :-)

Comment: What I want is a C# style bool TyrParse(string somethingToParse, out value). But I did not ask the question from the C# perspective because C# haters fond of Java start voting me down immediately. I do also realize there are no such things as out parameters in Java. So I am rather looking for a general solution to this. It is such a common problem there must be a common solution.

Comment: Guava has `Ints#tryParse` and `Long#tryParse` methods.

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) has some classes to help you with your tasks.

---

[NumberUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html) has methods:

[isNumber](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isNumber%28java.lang.String%29) - Checks whether the String a valid Java number.

[isParsable](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isParsable%28java.lang.String%29) - Checks whether the given String is a parsable number.

---

[DateUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html) contains a method [ParseDate](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html#parseDate%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29) which can be used to implement `isParsable` method for dates, according to your needs.

You can use these classes to implement you own simple framework to avoid `ParseExceptions` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the use case. Strings generated by another software are usually expected to be in the right format, so catching an exception in the unlikely case that they are not, is fine.

When it comes to user input, the simple parse routines like `Integer.parseInt` are insufficient anyway. You normally acquire a [`Format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/text/Format.html) object, appropriate to the data type and user language, which has the [`parseObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Format.html#parseObject-java.lang.String-java.text.ParsePosition-) method which allows to deal with errors. It will return `null` in case of an error and your `ParsePosition` object will be updated to reflect the position of the error.

Note that for types like `Date` there is no such primitive parse routine equivalent to `Integer.parseInt` anyway. The are always handled by a [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/text/DateFormat.html), so you always have a `Format` object and the question becomes meaningless.

Comment: But `DateFormat` also knows the overloaded `parse(...)`-method accepting a `ParsePosition`-argument, see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.text.ParsePosition-). Otherwise good answer.

Comment: @Meno Hochschild: I realized that the last sentence was misleading. I rewrote it to make the original intent clear.